# onChange() event for three select elements with common class is fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I have three select elements for "filters" for movie cards on home page of my application. They share common class name and onChange event is bound to it through jQuery. When I select any option, it correctly fires and executes functions. But when I remove same filter (change value to "none"), event is fired twice, displaying double set of cards. How can I prevent this?

HTML:

```
<form class="show-filter">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="language">Language</label>
          <select id="language" class="form-control filter">
            <option value="none" selected>Any</option>
            <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
            <option value="English">English</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="format">Format</label>
          <select id="format" class="form-control filter">
            <option value="none" selected>Any</option>
            <option value="2D">2D</option>
            <option value="3D">3D</option>
            <option value="iMax">iMax</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="genre">Genre</label>
          <select id="genre" class="form-control filter">
            <option value="none" selected>Any</option>
            <option value="Action">Action</option>
            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
            <option value="Fantacy">Fantacy</option>
            <option value="Crime">Crime</option>
            <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
            <option value="Biopic">Biopic</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
var language="none";
        var format="none";
        var genre="none";

        $(".filter").on("change",function(e){
        
        document.getElementById("movie-cards").innerHTML=''; 
             if(e.target.id==="genre")
             genre=e.target.value;
             else  if(e.target.id==="language")
             language=e.target.value;
             else  if(e.target.id==="format")
             format=e.target.value;
             getData(language,format,genre); //function takes filter params and returns data for movie-cards.
         });

const getData = (language,format,genre) => {
    var url="http://localhost:8080?language="+language+"&format="+format+"&genre="+genre;
    sendHttpRequest('GET', url).then(responseData => {
      createMovieCards(responseData)
    });
  };
```

I have also tried using the class name only binding to form and not all select elements. it works exactly same.

- [Initial page before filter selction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OlOu.png)
- [Page after adding filter
  for genre= horror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTmyT.png)
- [Page after removing the filter again (calling
  getData("none","none","none") as initial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LmNC.png)

Comment: I would take a look at getData. The event is fiering once if this is removed: https://jsfiddle.net/wrosqjd3/2/

Comment: Hi, Thank you @Selva, for efforts. Kindly Refer Edits. It calls Spring REST method which gathers infor of all movies in DB and sends it back.